# The similar questions blurb is too sticky

Tags: bug, design

Answered here: [Right-hand sidebar covers the footer on the "ask question" page and markdown help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel)

*I can't title.*

The Similar questions blurp does not stop at the "footer" of the page.
Indecently the "How to Format" on meta does the same thing.

[image]

It uses the following `class="module newuser sidebar-help"`

Comment: Probably by design -- it's more valuable information than the list of other sites in the network.

Comment: lol. How do i have 2k permisiions?

Comment: @Stingervz , What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: AFAIK only 2k users have vote to close permissions.

Comment: It seems to have changed that if you are the owner of the question you can do it as well

Comment: @Stingervz [If you have 250 rep and are the owner of the post,](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) you can view close votes and vote to close your own post. Otherwise, you need 3k rep.